# Nivo slider image flicker

Tags: jquery, css, sharepoint, nivo-slider

This used to work fine, but I recently uploaded new images and I now notice a flicker in them.

This is integrated into my sharepoint site. The new images are not particularly larger than the other ones.

Here is my css:

```
/* The Nivo Slider styles */
.nivoSlider {
    position:relative;
}
.nivoSlider img {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}
/* If an image is wrapped in a link */
.nivoSlider a.nivo-imageLink {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:40%;
    border:0;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    z-index:1;
    display:none;
}
/* The slices and boxes in the Slider */
.nivo-slice {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    /*z-index:5;*/
    height:100%;
}
.nivo-box {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    /*z-index:5;*/
}
/* Caption styles */
.nivo-caption {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
    opacity:0.8; /* Overridden by captionOpacity setting */
    width:100%;
    /*z-index:8;*/
}
.nivo-caption p {
    padding:5px;
    margin:0;
}
.nivo-caption a {
    display:inline !important;
}
.nivo-html-caption {
    display:none;
}
/* Direction nav styles (e.g. Next & Prev) */
.nivo-directionNav a {
    position:absolute;
    top:45%;
    /*z-index:9;*/
    cursor:pointer;
}
.nivo-prevNav {
    left:0px;
}
.nivo-nextNav {
    right:0px;
}
/* Control nav styles (e.g. 1,2,3...) */
.nivo-controlNav a {
    position:relative;
    /*z-index:9;*/
    cursor:pointer;
}
.nivo-controlNav a.active {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us an example? Make a new jsfiddle project if you can't show the origin.

Comment: you can actually take a look at w w w DOT r e v a l DOT c o m

Comment: jQuery Nivo Slider v2.6
jquery-1.5.1.js

Answer (score 2):

I have seen similar issues before.  A fix that usually works pretty well is setting:

```
opacity: 1;
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
zoom: 1;
```

On the image.